# Jruby On Rails app gives LocalJumpError on Tomcat when makig a WAR with Warble

Tags: tomcat, jruby, warbler

So I made a small app that doesn't do much. It just has a controller with an index method that does some math. It's a test app. I wanted this test app to run on Tomcat wrapped in a WAR.

When I deploy this app on TOmcat is gives me :

LocalJumpError

yield called out of block.

The app work fine with WebRick. Can someone point me to how to solve this problem ? I have no ideea were to start.

Thank you
PS
I have 
- jruby-1.6.2(rvm)
- warble 1.3.1
- Tomcat 6

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message with a rails 3.0.9 app because of a invalid entry in the database.yml (wrong username/password). I assume the war file uses the production environment - check your production database settings.